# Regex ^ \\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}$

Tags: regex

I've to format a date into a specific format **^\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}$**. I'm searching now for a while and can't find a solution. I found these [\\d{3}-\\d{4}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8582521/what-does-this-regular-expression-mean-d3-d4m), [\d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479423/does-d-in-regex-mean-a-digit)
that nearly matches my requirements but I can't figure out why it doesn't match. I'm testing with [regex101](https://regex101.com/)

As far I understand it, the first entry should work.

```regex
2021-11-10
```

```regex
"1234-12-34"
```

I also tried to copy characters from an Ascii-table to ensure they are not special.

Comment: In regex101 you should unescape the slashes (replace `\\d` with `\d`), otherwise the pattern matches '\' and 'd' characters instead of numbers.

Comment: Try to escape the minus sign, it is considered a range operator. That is, your regex should look like this `\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}`. This regex on the other hand matches any lower letter from a to z `[a-z]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove the `^` and the `$`

```
\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}
```

`^` matches the start of line and `$` matches the end of line. So the second entry has `"` after the start and before the end, it doesn't match.

Depending on your language, no need to double backslashes (`\\`):

```
\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}
```

Doubling backslash is used for escaping purpose.

Comment: There is a line break at the end of line, but  I tried it without still doesn't work.

Comment: The second supposed to be another testing example. Sorry for that confusion, I edited it. I tried to remove **^** and **$** with no effect.

Comment: @heaxyh Depending on your language, you can do with single `\\`s.

Answer (score 0):

### Using POSIX Character Classes

You don't mention a language, so I'm not sure why you're escaping your backslash characters. If you're looking for a portable solution, you can do this with POSIX character classes rather than the `\d` atom which (while fairly common these days) is certainly not universal.

For example, this anchored expression:

```
    ^[[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2}$
```

will match with any extended regex engine I know, including egrep, pcregrep, Ruby, GNU awk, GNU sed (with the `-r` flag), and others. As an example:

```sh
    $ echo "2021-11-10" | egrep '^[[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2}$'
    2021-11-10
```

### Caveats

1. It won't work with engines that don't understand the `{}` length atom (e.g. BSD grep without the `-E` flag).
2. It will validate the *format*, but won't actually ensure that it's a valid *date*. For that, you need a tool that understands dates, such as GNU date. For example:

   ```
    $ date -d '2021-11-10'
    Wed Nov 10 00:00:00 EST 2021

    $ date -d '1234-12-34'
    date: invalid date ‘1234-12-34’
   ```
3. Regular expressions are powerful, but they aren't always the right solution to every problem, especially if the problem is one of data validation.

Comment: thanks for your deep explanation, but I can't tell which regex interpreter they use. I got it from an API, where they keep their language secret.